# D3.js: updating links between elements in a radial tree upon collapse/expand

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tree, geometry

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263161/d3-js-adding-links-between-elements-in-a-radial-tree-hierarchical-edge-bundling).

I have managed to add links between elements in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bd2kqst/12/) using parts of the code found in the [original hierarchical edge bundling](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) by Mike Bostock and added them to radial version of the [collapsible tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083):

```
var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.85)
    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var middleLinks = packageImports(root);

svg.selectAll("path.middleLink")
          .data(bundle(middleLinks))
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "middleLink")
          .attr("d", line);
```

The "packageImport" function can be found at the bottom.

I am now trying to update those links whenever I collapse/expand an element and I have no idea how to go about it. It might have something to do with the following part or the parts inside the update function when positions are changed:

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update(d);
}
```

Also it is worth mentioning that removing the following line yields another correct layout with no children collapsed:

```
root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);
```

For this reason I do not understand why the update after the click function doesn't take into account the new layout.

Feel free to edit the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bd2kqst/12/).

Another possibility would that the inner level doesn't move and is always set to the spacing of the all expanded size, and therefore the second level would just appear or disappear and not change the first level and would still fit. You may suggest this solution as an answer, *but it is still plan B*.

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually updating their values. All the below code does is update **new** links, which you don't have any of,

```
svg.selectAll("path.middleLink")
.data(bundle(middleLinks))
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "middleLink")
.attr("d", line);
```

You can correct this by updating the existing links in addition to new ones,

```
var middle = svg.selectAll("path.middleLink")
  .data(bundle(middleLinks));
middle.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "middleLink")
  .attr("d", line);
middle.attr("d", line);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mgw37tk/